Issues with getServerSideProps and experimental-edge runtime on Cloudflare Workers with Next.js
I'm working on a Next.js project using version 13.5.6 and deploying it to Cloudflare Workers. I've set up my project to use the experimental-edge runtime for server-side rendering with getServerSideProps. The static pages work fine, but the pages with getServerSideProps are not functioning as expected after deployment.
Here's my setup:
package.json scripts:
"scripts": {
    "dev": "env-cmd -f local.env next dev",
    "clean": "rm -rf ./.next",
    "start": " next start -p 2053",
    "start:staging": "next start -p 3113 ",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "pages:build": "env-cmd -f dev.env npx @cloudflare/next-on-pages",
    "pages:deploy": "npm run pages:build && wrangler pages deploy .vercel/output/static",
    "pages:watch": "npx @cloudflare/next-on-pages --watch",
    "pages:dev": "npx wrangler pages dev .vercel/output/static --compatibility-date=2023-12-06 --compatibility-flag=nodejs_compat"
  }

Deployment Command:
npm run pages:build
Issue:
After deploying, the static pages work perfectly, but the pages with getServerSideProps do not render as expected.it returns with Internal Server Error
Verified that the experimental-edge runtime is correctly set in the page files
Checked Cloudflare Workers logs for any specific errors but couldn't pinpoint the issue.

I was facing a similar issue and fixed it by removing this part of my code
import { jitsuAnalytics } from "@jitsu/js"

export const analytics = jitsuAnalytics({
  host: jitsuHost,
  writeKey: jitsuWriteKey,
})

Start removing any code used in the page visited, including "_app.tsx" file, until the error is gone.
I am guessing some packages will cause errors on edge runtime with cloudflare. And for some reason this only happens with pages router "getServerSideProps", didn't face this issue with app router.
